# difference of 2 layers in gimp

Tags: image-processing, gimp

Is it possible to recover a black & white overprinted document?
A hard to get paper accidentally landed in the printer tray and got overprinted with another document.  Is it possible to somehow recover the original with layer tricks? No, I cannot reprint the original and no simple way to get a copy.

Technically, I have 2 layers:

- A + B = scan of the damaged, overprinted document
- B = scan of the document printed over A

I need to extract A

So, technically I should be able to somehow recover only those black points from the A+B layer, that are black on both layers. I know it is not going to be perfect, but at least I will have the content back. Can someone please help me?

Comment: why not simply rewrite the document? your brain and vision is superior to any image processing attempts in such a scenario...

Answer (score 0):

*"So, technically I should be able to somehow recover only those black points from the A+B layer"* Uh? A white + B black = A+B black, A black + B black = A+B black. In other words, in A+B, you can't tell the origin of all the black pixels that are also black in B. Unless there are minute differences in density between B and A+B, but you would have to provide some samples (and it would require careful scanning, or even taking professional-grade pictures with a good camera since it would likely have more dynamic range than a scanner).

In the meantime, if you want to remove all of B, even if it removes some of A,

- load A+B
- load B over it
- `Color>Invert` B
- Set B to "Lighten only" mode

Comment: What I meant is a transformation or script that goes trough the canvas, pixel by pixel, like (pseudocode):
`IF point(x,y) on layer "A+B" = black AND point(x,y) on layer "B" is black 
THEN set point(x,y) on layer "Recover" to black 
ELSE set point(x,y) on layer "Recover" to white
END IF`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but just in case anyone else needs the answer... I ran into a similar problem, and what I did was the following.  In Gimp:

- File > Open... the combined image (this should appear as a single layer)
- File > Open as layers... the image printed over the desired document
- Select the layer containing the second image
- Layer > Stack > Layer to Top
- In the Layer panel, right click on top layer > Edit Layer Attributes...
- Set mode to "Color erase" and click OK

Since we don't have a record of what document A had in each pixel we cannot determine which pixels had content in both document A and B.  So, what this technique leaves us with is a clear image of document A with slight gaps where lines from the two documents overlap.